# How to find the coefficient of $x^8$ in the following:

Tags: generating-functions

I need to find the coefficient of $x^8$ in the following using generating functions:

$$\frac{(1+x)^2}{1-3x} $$

I attempted to write out three different generating functions adding together to give the numerator with a common denominator of $1-3x$. But this has led me no where. Any hints would be appreciated, even in the general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the geometric series to expand the denominator (assuming $|x|<\frac13$) and then multiply with $(1+x)^2$. More specifically $$\begin{align*}\frac{(1+x)^2}{1-3x}&=(x^2+2x+1)\cdot\frac{1}{1-3x}=(x^2+2x+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(3x)^n=\\&=(x^2+2x+1)\left(1+3x+(3x)^2+\ldots+(3x)^6+(3x)^7+(3x)^8+\ldots\right)=\\&=\ldots+x^2\cdot(3x)^6+2x\cdot(3x)^7+(3x)^8+\ldots=\\&=\left(3^6+2\cdot3^7+3^8\right)x^8+\ldots\end{align*}$$ where in the last equations I wrote only the terms concerning $x^8$. So the requested coefficient is equal to $$3^6+2\cdot3^7+3^8$$ assuming $|x|<\frac13$.

Comment: Ahh, how simple that was; yet I could not think of that on my own. Makes me feel pretty stupid. Thank you.

Comment: @Frumpy You are welcome! Do not worry, earlier today, I could not solve a probability exercise that someone else solved with a very nice way, so today I feel pretty stupid too...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\mbox{With}\ \verts{x} < {1 \over 3}\,;\qquad{\pars{1 + x}^{2} \over 1 - 3x}&=
\pars{1 + 2x + x^{2}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{3x}^{n}
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{3^{n}x^{n} + 2\times 3^{n}x^{n + 1}
+ 3^{n}x^{n + 2}}
\end{align}

> Solution:
>   $$
> 3^{8} + 2\times 3^{7} + 3^{6} = 3^{6}\times 16 = \color{#00f}{\Large 11664}
> $$